# how to make of a copy of any file(any extension) from one path to another using java(on windows)?

Tags: java, windows, file-copying

I need to copy 1.jpg from F:\ to E:\ on windows,need some help in using the method `static void copyFile(File srcFile, File destFile)` I found this on https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html.
What corrections do I need to make to the following code ?

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
public class copyt1 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    copyFile(F:\1.jpg,E:\);
  }
}
```

Comment: For one thing, put your paths in double quotes. For another, you'd almost certainly need the `1.jpg` on the end of the destination.

Comment: If you post a code example it should be either pseudo code and recognizable as such, or actual code that compiles. The above example does not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the NIO2 package - more specifically `Files.copy()`.

Additional information available [here](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2882984/core-java/nio2-cookbook-part-1.html)